# How can I change the minimum value of the vertical axis with apps script in a embeddedchart (google sheets)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 'manually' created a chart in google sheets by selecting a range and inserting a stacked column chart:

[manual chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbK00.png)

I changed  the vertical axis minimum value to 79.000.000.

However, I would like to automate this process. So, therefore I wrote a little script:

```
 /**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function buildChart() {
  // Get the sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //Create new chart
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COLUMN)
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("D1:H8"))

    .setPosition(10, 10, 0, 0)
    //.setOption('title', 'Cost Price Development - Stage 3')
    .setOption('isStacked', 'TRUE')
    .setOption('colors', ['tranparant', '#93CCEA', 'green', 'black'])
    .setOption('vAxis.title', 'test test')
    //.setOption('vAxis', {'title': 'Something Here'})
    //.setOption('vAxis.viewWindowMode', 'explicit')  
    .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', 79000000)
    //.setOption('vAxis.textStyle.fontSize',8)
    .build();

  // Insert chart in sheet
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

With the line

```
.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', 79000000)
```

I want to change the minimum value of the vertical axis. However, the vertical axis does still start at 0 instead op 79.000.000.

I have also tried:

```
 .setOption('vAxis.minValue', 79000000)
```

which does not help either: the code above results in the following chart:

[chart with apps script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxijW.png)

Answer (score 4):

I solved it with this code line:

```
setOption('vAxes', {0: {title: '€', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, titleTextStyle: {fontSize : 8}, viewWindow: {min: 79000000}}})
```

So, I used vAxes instead of vAxis.

Comment: I know this was from a while ago but I have been scratching my head over the same problem for several hours now not understanding why `.setOption("vAxis.viewWindow.min", num)` hasn't been working. Still don't understand why as it's right in the manual but the `.setOption("vAxes", {0: {viewWindow: {min: num}}})` did work. Thank you!